# PowerShell - Work with counter and renaming of files

Tags: powershell, syntax, count

Please help with the following situation:

There are many photos need to be renamed according to the name of directory folder, where they are located + add index at the end of each new name in format PHOTO1000_NAMEA_1, PHOTO1001_NAMEA_2, PHOTO1002_NAMEB_1, PHOTO1003_NAMEB_2, PHOTO1004_NAMEC_1, PHOTO1005_NAMEC_2, etc.

Where:

a) PHOTO1000 (1001,1002) = counter of total quantity of renamed photos;
b) _1 (_2,_3) = indexing number of concrete new name of item.

In my version of code in part a) counter did not calculate items from "1000", i++.

```
$count=1000
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.jpg | ForEach-Object -Process { Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_ -NewName ("PHOTO_{0}_{1}{2}" -f $script:count, $_.Directory.Name,$_.Extension) -WhatIf }
```

Please help with correct format of code.

Thanks!!

Comment: Filenames are strings.  So to append you can use the plus sign :  "PHOTO1003_NAMEB" + "_2"

Answer (score 2):

You can use two [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) in combination with a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) to implement your task:

```bash
$totalCount  = @{ value = 0 } # count of renamed files overall
$countPerDir = @{ } # count of renamed files per directory name
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.jpg | 
  Rename-Item -NewName {
    'PHOTO_{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}' -f ++$totalCount.value, 
                               $_.Directory.Name, 
                               ++$countPerDir[$_.Directory.Name], 
                               $_.Extension 
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- By using [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item), you're actually renaming the files *in place*, not in a single, flat target directory; if you want the latter, use [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) with its `-Destination` parameter instead.
- The only reason `$totalCount` is a hashtable rather than a simple `[int]` variable is that delay-bind script blocks run in a *child* scope of the caller (unlike `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` script blocks), and referencing a hashtable from the child scope enables updating its entries across scope boundaries.
- The `$countPerDir` hashtable keeps track of how any files *per directory name* have been renamed. `++$countPerDir[$_.Directory.Name]` takes advantage of two behaviors:

  - Assigning to an entry that didn't previously exists implicitly *creates* such an entry (with the given key).
  - Applying `++` to new entry that was just created effectively treats it like `0` and returns `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a solution as I understood your question.
Make sure to use the voting mechanism to mark the correct answer if satisfied with what was provided.

```
# Set the path to the directory containing the photos to rename
$dirPath = "C:\Temp\Photo"

$counter = 1000

# Get all directories in the specified path
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $dirPath -Directory -Recurse

# Loop through each directory
foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
    # Get all files in the current directory
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.FullName -File -Filter '*.jpg'

    # Initialize a counter for the current file index
    $index = 1

    # Loop through each file in the current directory
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        # Build the new file name
        # ("PHOTO_{0}_{1}{2}" -f $script:count, $_.Directory.Name,$_.Extension)
        if ($file.BaseName.StartsWith('PHOTO')) {
            Write-Warning ('File {0} has alread been renamed' -f $file.FullName)
            Continue
        }
        $newName ='PHOTO{0}_{1}_{2}{3}' -f  $counter,$file.BaseName,$index, $file.Extension

        # Rename the file
        Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newName

        # Increment the file index
        $index++
        $counter++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't see you calling $counter. You initiate it, but don't call it again in the foreach.

You have 2 counters going - total of all photos, and then index which is based off of NAME_ which looks like the directory name.

First counter is easy - just add $counter++ after each iteration. $index just needs to be based off of directory - probably simplest way to do this is group everything off of directory, and then $index++

behold - my answer

```
$jpgs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.jpg | group -Property Directory

$counter = 1000    
foreach ($group in $jpgs) {
    $index = 1
    foreach ($item in $group.Group) {
        rename-item -LiteralPath $item -NewName ("PHOTO{0}_{1}_{2}{3}" -f 
        $counter, $item.Directory.Name,$index ,$item.Extension) - 
        WhatIf;$counter++;$index++}}
```

behold - my results

```
Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Doco\Downloads\20220721_140129.jpg Destination: C:\Users\Doco\Downloads\PHOTO1000_Downloads_1.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Doco\Downloads\IMG_20220720_211337_720.jpg Destination: C:\Users\Doco\Downloads\PHOTO1001_Downloads_2.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Doco\Downloads\IMG_20220720_211337_773.jpg Destination: C:\Users\Doco\Downloads\PHOTO1002_Downloads_3.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Doco\Downloads\IMG_20220721_203852_286.jpg Destination: C:\Users\Doco\Downloads\PHOTO1003_Downloads_4.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Doco\OneDrive\Desktop\birthday invite.jpg Destination: C:\Users\Doco\OneDrive\Desktop\PHOTO1004_Desktop_1.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Doco\OneDrive\Desktop\boop.jpg Destination: C:\Users\Doco\OneDrive\Desktop\PHOTO1005_Desktop_2.jpg".
```

Now just remove -whatif. Obviously

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version, using reference variables for the counters:

```
[ref]$Total = 0
(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse) | ForEach {
    $_ | Get-ChildItem *.jpg -File | ForEach -Begin {[ref]$subTotal = 0} -Process {
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName {
            'Photo_{0:d4}_{1}_{2}{3}' -f $Total.Value++ , $_.Directory.Name , $subTotal.Value++ , $_.Extension
        } -WhatIf
    }
}
```